# Updating Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, uefi, system-installation

I've updated my Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS before but now I installed Ubuntu and partitioned my hard disk about 10 times, trying to do everything but it can't be updated to 14.04 LTS again without saying something like "partial update, errors in some packages"!

The command is

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

I have a dual uefi processor 'intel g630 2.7ghz'

Comment: The 14.04 has not been released yet, please try this again the day after tomorrow when the final release will be out.

Comment: 14.04 LTS !! I had it before ,man from the command above

Comment: partial update means you did not update 13.10 before trying the upgrade to 14.04 (there is probably a kernel update in between that you need to do 1st).

Comment: I know you did, nevertheless, it has not been released yet. What you installed is a beta version and will be until the official release which is [coming tomorrow](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule). That said, your specific problem is probably what Rinzwind said above.

Comment: Thanks Guys Btw ,, I Made sudo make upgrade then installed blender ,wine and playonlinux and All Things Are Awesome ^_^ :D

Answer (score 0):

Annoying that the GUI updater didnt indicate an upgrade availabe after checking twice thismorning, so going through the terminal sudo do-release-upgrade -d

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the update to reach all mirrors or change your sources mirror to a mirror that has the update. I don't how to pick such a mirror but I got it the first time.